# RPC: Is there a way to call RPC function through Javascript? Can someone please head me in that direction

Tags: javascript, web-applications, server, rpc

I am trying to create a website that will call an RPC function through Javascript.

Comment: RPC is a rather generic term. Are you trying to interface with an existing API or what? Please explain a bit more, preferably by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53185613/edit) the question.

Comment: "I am looking for a recipe for a food that will be eaten with cutlery" is exactly as precise, and answerable, as your question :) It would be good if you could add some details to what exactly you are trying to do, and what kind of cutlery, i mean, RPC, you intend to make use of.

Comment: This is quite a broad question, so it's difficult to be too precise. It's certainly possible, you need to make a post request in a particular format, but what that format is depends very heavily on your implementation